# How to delete all data from tables in a SQL Server 2014 database, but keep all the tables?

Tags: sql

As stated I need help deleting all data from every table in a test database. There are 3477 tables and some of the tables were created by a past employee so I was unable to create a schema of the DB and recreate it empty.

Is there a fast way to delete all of the data and keep all of the tables and their structure? Also, I noticed when deleting data from the DB with Delete table_name, that the data file wasn't decreasing in size. Any reason why? Then I tried to just delete the data file to see what would happen and it erased everything, so i had to restore the test database. Now I'm back at block one....

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.... I've read a lot and everything just says use Delete or Truncate, but rather not do that for 3477 tables.

Comment: To clarify, when the data file was deleted it erased EVERYTHING, tables, data and all objects.

Comment: query tables from information_schema.tables, loop thru them and truncate the data.

Comment: You use `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` on every table. There isn't any shortcut. Now... you can dynamically generate those DELETE statements and then execute all of them en masse, so it really isn't that much work.

Comment: I did macro all the Delete statements and ran through around 200 tables and when it finished, I could no longer connect to the database. No sure what happened, so skeptical to try that again.

Answer (score 1):

The `TRUNCATE TABLE` command deletes the data inside a table, but not the table itself.

You have a lot of tables (more than 3000...), so take a look to following link to truncate all tables:

[Truncate all tables in a SQL Server database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3218/truncate-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database/)

Comment: I'll take a look at that.

thanks!